# grayscale effect doesnt work when using negative z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, grayscale

I created this jsbin webpage to show you what im trying to explain.. The effect works just 
fine when using positive z-indexes but if i change for example the z-index of the #flower id 
to -2 and the #front id to -1 it doesn´t work anymore... i dont know why this happens. Any explanation 
would be really appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/xexusaci/1/edit

```
#flower{
          position:relative;
          top:-600px;
          left:50px;
          z-index:1;
        }

      #front {
          z-index:2;
          position:relative;
          top:100px;
          height:600px;
          width:100%;
          background-color:lightblue;   
        }

       #flower{
          filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg     xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscalerayscale");
          filter: gray;
          -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        #flower:hover {
           filter: none;
           -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like it works fine to me in Chrome. Is this browser specific?

Comment: Does the body have an implicit z-index of 0?

Comment: You may wanna see [THIS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78087)

Comment: Very old bug, presume is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Not related to z-indices, but your SVG ID does not match the URL anchor, so it must be broken in Gecko.

```
url("data:...filter id='grayscale'...#grayscalerayscale")
```

Other than that, cannot reproduce described bug in Fx 28 nor Chrome 33.